# Efficiently serializing multiple objects that need to make REST call

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Say I have a simple model, `Account`, as follows:

```
    class Account(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(db_index=True)
```

And an `AccountSerializer` as follows:

```
    class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        name = CharField(source="account.name")
        def _get_favorite_color(self, obj: Account):
            # Make a rest call to get this account's favorite color
            favorite_color = _get_favorite_color(name)
```

I also have a `ViewSet` with a `list` action to get all accounts, as well as a `Serializer`, to serialize each item. The `JSON` returned has the following shape:

```
{
    'accounts':[
        {'name':'dave', 'favorite_color':'blue'},
        {'name':'john', 'favorite_color':'black'},
    ]
}
```

What is the django-esque way of 'bulk' fetching these favorite colors? This `REST` call to obtain favorite colors can take as an input a list of all account `id`s and return them in a single list, avoiding making `n` REST calls when just one can do.

Where would this logic live to make the most sense? I can't put this logic in the `Serializer` considering that it only handles one object at a time. Is there another place to put it rather than the `ViewSet`? My understanding is that `ViewSet`s should be as lean as possible.

Comment: Viewsets use the serlaizers, so it makes sense to use the viewset to get what the serializer needs, and pass it on IMO

Comment: @BrianDestura I see, so what you are saying is that the `ViewSet` should make this `REST` call, and it would pass a list of these items to the `Serializer` so that it can properly set this field for every item it serializes?

Comment: Yep! The rest call's result can be passed to the serializer context

Answer (score 0):

You can use action decorator in Account Viewset to fetch the data wherein you can pass account ids in the url args.

```
@action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, url_name='favourite_color')
    def favourite_color(self, request, pk=None):
        account_ids = list(request.query_params.get('account_ids').split(","))
        queryset = Account.objects.filter(id__in=account_ids).values('favourite_color')
        # Not sure how favourite color is linked to account
        # You will get the values hitting one query, and you can make a json response which needs to be returned

        return Response(json_response_of_favourite_colors)
```

The Url would be somewhat like this:

url:  accounts/favourite_color/?account_ids=1,2,3